# Nginx redirect all old domain subdomains to new one

Tags: nginx, redirect, regex, 301-redirect

I had a very long domain, so I decided to change it to a shorter and more friendly one. But since I have a lot of subdomains (in fact, I have a subdomain wildcard), I wanted to keep the subdomain while changing only the domain part. So, I made the following rule:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^(\w+)\.olddomain\.com$;

  rewrite ^ $scheme://$1.doma.in$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

I have read a lot of other questions where this snippet solved the problem. But with me, Nginx always redirects to `.domain.in`, without any subdomains. What am I missing? I have tested the regex against regex101 and the examples work fine, Nginx seems unable to redirect it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since nginx 0.8.25 named captures can be used in server_name. You should use them.

Here, the sub-domain will be stored in a variable called `$sub`. Then you will be able to reuse it in the `rewrite` directive :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^(?<sub>\w+)\.olddomain\.com$;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://$sub.doma.in$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep your actual Regex and use `$1` in a `return` directive :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^(\w+)\.olddomain\.com$;
  return 301 $scheme://$1.doma.in$request_uri;
}
```

Finally, note that the `return` directive is the best approach for a redirect. You may run into [Pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if) using `rewrite` for a redirect.

Comment: Perfect. I used the return approach but still named the regex part, it is much more easy to understand.

Comment: What if we want to redirect without a subdomain (www) too? like: sub1.ex.to > sub1.new.in and ex.to > www.new.in?

Comment: Note that '\w' does *not* match certain characters which can be in domain names, e.g. '-'. The above regex will therefore redirect `test-sub.doma.in` to `.domai.in`!

Comment: use [\w\-\\_]+ instead of \w+ for subdomains that have - and _ in them

Comment: What does `~` in the regex do in the beginning? It doesn't make since that something would appear before `^` in regex.

Comment: `~` is for case sensitive regular expression match modifier. It doesn't mean that something would appear before `^`